# asp.net wizard activestepchange next button change validation group

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to know if this is possible, i have a wizard, and when i get on step 5 i need to change the buttons from next to finish button, because the Complete step of wizard doesn't show the steps and i need it to show, so i figure out a way to do things but i need that a button turns visible when it gets to step 5, but the problem is that it has to be done on activeStepChanged (I think).

here is the code:

```
protected void wizard1_ActiveStepChanged ( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    ((Button)(wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplate$btnNext"))).Visible = true;
    ((Button)(wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplate$btnFinish"))).Visible = false;
    switch(wizard1.ActiveStepIndex) {
        case 1:
            wizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep2);
            break;
        case 2:
            wizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep3);
            break;
        case 3:
            wizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep4);
            break;
        case 4:
            wizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep5);
            ((Button)(wizard1.FindControl("StartNavigationTemplateContainerID$btnNext"))).Visible = false;
            ((Button)(wizard1.FindControl("StartNavigationTemplateContainerID$btnFinish"))).Visible = true;
            break;
        case 5:
            wizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep6);
            break;
    }
}
```

is this possible to do? because when I run the code it says that the button is null, i tried other ways like this:

```
protected void wizard1_ActiveStepChanged ( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    Button btnNext = (Button)wizard1.FindControl("btnNext");
    Button btnFinish = (Button)wizard1.FindControl("btnFinish");
    btnNext.Visible = true;
    btnFinish.Visible = false;
    switch(wizard1.ActiveStepIndex) {
        case 1:
            wizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep2);
            break;
        case 2:
            wizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep3);
            break;
        case 3:
            wizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep4);
            break;
        case 4:
            wizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep5);
            btnNext.Visible = false;
            btnFinish.Visible = true;
            break;
        case 5:
            wizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep6);
            break;
    }
}
```

but it always return me that the button is null, is there any way to catch the button on ActiveStepChanged? If not what alternatives do I have to make this working?

here is the buttons code:

```
<StartNavigationTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="StartNextButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="SEGUINTE" CssClass="wizard-nav-buttons" ValidationGroup="valReg" CausesValidation="true" />
</StartNavigationTemplate>
<StepNavigationTemplate>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnPrevious" runat="server" Text="ANTERIOR" CommandName="MovePrevious" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="wizard-nav-buttons prev" />
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding-left: 10px;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="SEGUINTE" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="wizard-nav-buttons" />
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding-left: 10px;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnFinish" runat="server" OnClick="wizard1_FinishButtonClick" Text="SUBMETER PROPOSTA" CssClass="wizard-nav-buttons submeterProposta" CausesValidation="true" Visible="false" />
    </div>
</StepNavigationTemplate>
<FinishNavigationTemplate></FinishNavigationTemplate>
```

Thank you so far.

Comment: Your second example should find the control. Are you in a MasterPage by any chance? There's a recursive FindControl you can get from CodingHorror that'll work in a MasterPage.http://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/

Comment: I'm using a normal aspx page, I don't have master page in this project, i'm making a form to submit to database, so it can't be on the master page anyway

Comment: Is your finish button ID "btnFinishButton" or "FinishButton"? I bet your ID is off.

Comment: the id is FinishButton, but it return null values for both buttons, for the first example, you were right the id was off, but it returns me null for the btnNext

Comment: Have you tried getting the navigation template first, then getting the button inside the template? (It would be FindControl("NavigationTemplate").FindControl("ButtonID")?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and it's very simple actually, since i was trying to call the button before the ActiveStepIndex was even defined (pre-render) it couldn't be found (normal because it wasn't even created), so after several tries and 1 morning searching and testing, i tryed to put it after a case in the switch and it was found, so for those who could possible have this difficulty, here is the functional code:

```
protected void wizard1_ActiveStepChanged ( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    Button btnNext , btnFinish;
    switch(wizard1.ActiveStepIndex) {
        case 1:
            btnNext = (Button)wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("btnNext");
            btnFinish = (Button)wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("btnFinish");
            btnNext.ValidationGroup = "valAutUniq";
            btnNext.Visible = true;
            btnFinish.Visible = false;
            wizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep2);
            break;
        case 2:
            btnNext = (Button)wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("btnNext");
            btnFinish = (Button)wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("btnFinish");
            btnNext.ValidationGroup = "valAutUniq";
            btnNext.Visible = true;
            btnFinish.Visible = false;
            wizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep3);
            break;
        case 3:
            btnNext = (Button)wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("btnNext");
            btnFinish = (Button)wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("btnFinish");
            btnNext.ValidationGroup = "valFormPag";
            btnNext.Visible = true;
            btnFinish.Visible = false;
            wizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep4);
            break;
        case 4:
            btnNext = (Button)wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("btnNext");
            btnFinish = (Button)wizard1.FindControl("StepNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("btnFinish");
            btnNext.ValidationGroup = null;
            btnNext.Visible = false;
            btnFinish.Visible = true;
            wizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep5);
            break;
    }
}
```